# Read files with extension of 0.part, 1.part while writing csv file using Dask in python

Tags: python, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

I had a big data with millions of rows and thousands of columns. After doing operations using dask I wanted to write it in CSV file. While writing it in csv file using

> **df.to_csv(r'D:\Projects\Android_HL_TC\Out')**

where df is the dask dataframe.

The output was like

[image]

How to read back those csv files ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = dd.read_csv(r'D:\Projects\Android_HL_TC\Out\*.part')
```

should work, doesn't it?